# C++ Accessing QString within an if statement

Tags: c++, qt, if-statement

I'm using C++ with Qt and in Qt an area where you can edit the look of the program, so when a style is selected by the user it goes in to the style sheet and edit it, but that's where my issue is! I'm using an if statement to get what they selected from a QComboBox and a QList, but when i try to edit it I cannot access the QString within the if statement. So basically i'm wondering if their is a way to access a QString from within a if statement?

I get an error saying:

> var0 was not declared in this scope

example:

```
if(2 < 3) {
    QString var0 = "blue";
}

// Problem
qApp->setStyleSheet("QTextEdit { background-color: " + var0 + ";}");
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: If the condition for the if statement was false what would you expect the `setStyleSheet` call to do?

Comment: i had an `else` statement set in to none so for example it would say `background-color: none;`

Comment: You should try to make your example as complete as possible so we don't have to guess at what you might have been thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var0` is declared in the scope of the if statement, it does not live after it. (Even the resources of the QString object are released.) You need to declare `var0` outside the if:

```
QString var0;
if(2 < 3) {
    var0 = "blue";
}

// No problem
qApp->setStyleSheet("QTextEdit { background-color: " + var0 + ";}");
```